# Migrating codeigniter to another server

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter, migration

I'm new with codeigniter and right now I'm trying to migrate a codeigniter application to another server. This application was in another server and now I want to move it to another server. In this server I have also a wordpress website and it works perfectly.

Firstly, what I have done it's a backup from the mysql database and from the files and I have move them via ftp to the another server under the /inventarios folder, so if I wrote on my browser

```
http://xxxxxx.com/inventarios
```

I should see the codeigniter application but what I receive it's a 404 error with the Wordpress interface

I have change the database.php and the another files from the config folder and it doesn't work. Why?. Under the inventarios folder I don't have a .htaccess file. Could you help me,please?. Thanks and let me know if you need more details.

**EDIT 01**

The htaccess which I have in the root folder is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I don't know if inside of inventarios I should place another htaccess.

Thanks so much

Comment: If u r using codignitor framework inside the wordpress than Abdullah's answer will solve yur issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create sub-folder with name of **`inventarios`** in root of your host. Inside the folder upload all your CI folders(application, system, index....).

Then go to **`application/config/config.php`**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://xxxxxx.com/inventarios';
```

Comment: Thanks so much Abdulla and devpro, I have done it and I have restart the apache and it doesn't work. the url is this: www.arteglobal.es (wordpress) and arteglobal.es/inventarios it would be the codeigniter.

Comment: @Charly66 did you create subfolder ??

Comment: Yes, I did it. I did it on the root folder of my host on var/www/html/inventarios

Comment: Nope, this is an internet server in a virtual server.

Comment: your htaccess redirect the page to wordpress

Comment: I have written the htaccess which I have on my root folder in a post

Comment: so @Abdulla, what I should do?. Thanks so much.

Comment: create subdomain and set to this path and try once. i hope you have uploded all the ci stuffs aswell

Answer (score 1):

Also /application/config/database.php is to be edited

Answer (score 0):

```
application/config/config.php
application/config/database.php
```

Don't forget to update .htaccess in root if there're some updates or url redirects to old `domain/url`